# Unable to join Wi-Fi network without carrier service

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone

I have an Verizon iPhone 4s and would like to use Wi-Fi until I decide on a service provider.

The phone has been reset to factory settings and sees my Wi-Fi network, but when I enter my password and hit join it says it's unable to join the network.

Updated to iOS 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Accessing WiFi without carrier service is possible.

To do that turn ON the airplane mode.

That will disable any carrier.

Comment: I tried the airplane mode already. No luck with the airplane mode. I don't have a carrier service at the moment. I know it works without one, because my wife's phone is receiving text messages without a carrier. Just by using our Wifi.

Comment: I misunderstood your question then, it has nothing to do with carrier. You WiFi is simply not working (not connecting) after factory reset!

Comment: Try with selecting the network and then tap Forget this network. Now start from beginning and use the join a network.